# how to fix screenrotation to same webpage

Tags: android, sdk, rotation, target, min

When the phone is rotation, the app is going to the startpage, but i want that it stays on the same page.

I've searched on google and stackoverflow but can't find any solution.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.farugh.neshaniha"
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="10.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.solidos.neshaniha.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And when i upload the app to the store, it says it's not designed for tablets.. How can i change that? Must it be with targetsdk and minsdk? And wich values i must use for tablets and all phones?

Kind regards,
Marvin

Comment: Add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" and try.

Comment: Please upvote and Accept the answer in answer's section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" and try.

Answer (score 0):

For tablet issue on market.

Remove below code from manifest.

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

because you put this two variable true

```
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

in manifest and in your project `drawable-sw600dp-mdpi` `drawable-xhdpi` `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` either this folder not availble in `res folder` or either it's empty.
android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"

Comment: I've tryed but google play says:
Your layout must use the available space on tablets
For your APK only use hardware functions that's available on tablets.

How i can fix this?

Comment: do you have all layout design in res folder?

Comment: wich layout ill forgot then?

Comment: your activity layout.

Comment: I have made the folders you said in res folder.. what do you mean with activity layout?